# Which windows font displays window closing button?

Tags: windows, fonts

[image: Close-Button on windows is missing]

As you can see in my attached screenshot my windows has a issue displaying the closing button. I am thinking that a font is missing. Do you know which font i have to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following a step-by-step suggestion by
http://www.withsteps.com/3483/windows-10-pro-default-fonts-download.html

I have been able to install all default windows 10 fonts.
The missing windows 10 font was also included.

**Finally, to solve this problem you need to download a package with all windows 10 fonts and reinstall every one.**